Good rigorous reference for wave phenomena
I'm interested in revisiting the physics of waves that I learned in college (diffraction, refraction, dispersion, interference) from a rigorous point of view, but I haven't found a PDE book which covers this type of topic. Would anyone have a suggestion?

Would it be possible to explain in what way this question is opinion-based? It reads to me like a simple reference request.

Maybe if you just delete the word "good" from the title?

"Linear and Nonlinear Waves" by G. B. Whitham (Wiley) fits the bill here. It's intended for first and second year graduate students, but it's approachable enough that someone who is familiar with undergraduate PDEs should have no trouble reading it.
I would also nominate "The Mathematics of Diffusion" by J. Crank (Oxford) as a resource specifically for diffusion mechanics. I'd put it at around the same level as the Whitham text in terms of difficulty/approachability.
Both of these texts are rigorous, but they aren't exactly theoretical. They involve what is essentially case studies on specific classes of equations, reaching solutions and analyzing the behavior.
If want a theoretical treatment, I couldn't recommend any text more than "Partial Differential Equations" by L. Evans (AMS). It covers broader classes of equations which contain those covered by the other texts, but it much less focused on solution methods.
